# Why when I do a git Merge Request in a new branch with my new commits, comes up very old commits (maybe never merged it?)?

Tags: git, gitlab

I follow the next git steps:

1. From my master I will create a new branch:

   ```
   git checkout -b "fix bug"
   ```
2. I do some code changes then I do:

   ```
   git add myfile/dlsjf.java

   git commit -m "fix bug"
   git push
   ```
3. Then I am going to create a MR from my branch to upstream/master and here is the problem:
   5 commits appears in the merge, my commit that I wanted to merge "fix bug" and other 3 commits (3) like :

   ```
   "Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/master'"
   ```

and the most strange for me an old commit from 5 months ago, why?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Please check out that local master point to the remote one. It is useful to integrate your local branch with remote master/main as follows: `git fetch origin; git rebase origin/master`

Comment: From which commit did you create the new branch? Are you accidentally on an old, unmerged branch of yours?

Comment: "Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/master'" sounds like you have executed `git pull` on your local "master" branch

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov if I do that (weel in my case git fetch upstream, because origin is my fork) there was a git merge conflic that I solve it then with git status :
```Your branch and 'origin/fix-tests' have diverged,
and have 4 and 9 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```
And after git pull (on my local branch) I tried to do my MR (against upstream master) and instead of 5 commits now comes up 10 commits to merge (It get worst situation that my initial situation)

Comment: @knittl I've created my new branch from my master(my fork origin/master), on the other hand related to git pull on my local branch, sorry for my beginner experience with git, but is it a bad practice or what?

Comment: If a merge request brings in extra commits, you created the branch from a wrong start-point.

Comment: @ElpieKay I created the new branch from my local master

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I've learned to create a clean branch from `git checkout upstream/main` then from this point create the feature branch git checkout -b "new-feature". On the other hand, if you are working and you want to update with main, then you do `git fetch -all` and later `git merge upstream/main` you will bring commits that don't belong to your branch then you will need to do some rebase tricks and pick your desired commits (for instance last 5) that you want to push:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~5
git commit -m"squashing last 5 commits"
git push -f 
git rebase upstream/main
git push -f
```